# What exactly triggers AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification?

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

So I know `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` is sent when a movie '[has played to its end time](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification)'.

My question is how does the player know if an item reaches its end time? I was playing a live stream generated by a 3rd party generator. It keeps updating the M3U8 and creating new TS files, which live streaming should do. But at some point my player receives an `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` and thus invokes my exit methods and quit. The 3rd party stream generator is still running OK though. I can restart the player and watch the streams.
Since the playing item is a live stream, `playerItem.duration` is not a readable duration number, which makes finding the End Time more like a black magic to me...

Really confused on how does the player thinks it's end. My guess is maybe the TS file was problematic and made the player think the whole playing is over? But if so, should the player change its status to say sth instead of silently finish playing?

P.S. I also tried different ways like make one ts missing from the m3u8 list, or stop generating new ones so that the player would play current m3u8 and play past the last ts, nothing made the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` magic happen....

I registered the notification as following: 
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                    selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                    name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                    object:self.playerItem];`

Comment: Are you sure it's not just auto-hooking into a new stream on exit?

Comment: "What exactly triggers AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification?" - put a breakpoint in a method that is registered for it, run in debuggger, wait for breakpoint to be hit, `backtrace`, `frame 1`, profit.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks for answering! Yeah I'm sure, the player stops playing and does not read anything from the server where the m3u8 is from..

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for answring! Not sure if I understand your answer correctly.. I updated my question to include how I registered it. From stack trace I can only tell that `playerItemDidReachEnd` was called in Thread 1 in my controller, but I still don't know why `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` was sent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So.. it turns out that the problem is from the 3rd party stream generator. It had sth ('IV', as in [Initialiation Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)) wrong when streaming the TS contents, so at some point AVPlayer read some spot on a TS, then consider the movie is finished, and thus sending `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`.... Not really an Objective-C issue I guess.

But my question of in what condition does `AVPlayer` send `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` is still unknown. If anyone knows any details about this, please feel free to update here. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

The last argument should be self.player not the playerItem

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.playerItem];
```

Comment: This is not correct. The notification is part of the AVPlayerItem class.